# I would like to send a notification email (Asana) whenever something is published (posts, pages, custom post types)

Tags: hooks, actions, publish

*The code below works perfectly*

When I create a new post, an email is sent out to the email included in the function.

**I would like to know how I can send an email when anything is published on the website, like custom post types, pages and regular posts**

```
function notifyauthor($post_id) {
 
$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
 
$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",
       
      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
       
      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
       
      Thanks"
      ;
       
   wp_mail("myemail@abcd.com", $subject, $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook that you're currently using is [`publish_<post type>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/) which means the `<post type>` part is dynamic and the value is a post type name/slug.

So for other post types like `page` and (a custom post type named) `my_cpt`, you would just need to change the "post" (or the `<post type>` part) in the hook name to `page`, `my_cpt` or whatever is the post type name/slug like so:

```php
add_action( 'publish_post', 'notifyauthor' );   // for the default 'post' post type
add_action( 'publish_page', 'notifyauthor' );   // for the default 'page' post type
add_action( 'publish_my_cpt', 'notifyauthor' ); // for a CPT with the name/slug my_cpt
```

Or if you want your action (`notifyauthor()`) to be called when *any* posts (regular Posts and Pages, and custom post types) is published, then you would want to use the [`transition_post_status()` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/transition_post_status/) instead of the `publish_<post type>` hook.

Here's an example based on [this on the WordPress Developer Resources site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/#comment-244):

```php
function wpdocs_run_on_publish_only( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    // Yes, I said "any posts", but you might better off specify a list of post
    // types instead. Or you could do the check in your notifyauthor() function
    // instead.
    $post_types = array( 'post', 'page', 'my_cpt', 'foo_bar', 'etc' );

    if ( ( 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ) &&
        in_array( $post->post_type, $post_types )
    ) {
        notifyauthor( $post->ID );
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpdocs_run_on_publish_only', 10, 3 );
```

PS: If you use the above code/hook, then you should remove the `add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');` from your current code.

Comment: PS 2: You don't need to call `notifyauthor()` in the `wpdocs_run_on_publish_only()` function; you could just rename that function to `notifyauthor` and put your code there which sends the email notification. :)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I will try this out and get back.